# ProperDivisors using For loop Current Code Breaks Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that looks at all possible divisors of a positive integer N and returns the sum of those divisors but not the number itself.

Exanple of what the function should return:

sumofProperDivisors(6) --> 6
sumofProperDivisors(12) --> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16

```
function sumofProperDivisors(n){
  var i = n;
  var b = 0;
  for (; i > 0;);
    if (n % i >= 2) {
      b = b + i;
      i--;
    }
    else i--;
return (b);
}
```

Comment: `;` at the end of for loop `for (; i > 0;);` makes it go creazy

Comment: This looks like its just a syntax error - or multiple errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop due to the semicolon `;` at the end of your for loop at line 4. Remove it and it executes. It still wouldn't give you the expected result because the logic also needs some tweaking.

```js
function sumofProperDivisors(n) {
  var i = n;
  var b = 0;
  for (; i > 0; i--) {
    if (n % i === 0 && n !== i) {
      b = b + i;
    }
  }
  return (b);
}

console.log(sumofProperDivisors(6));
```

Comment: This returns 4 instead of 6 any idea why?

Comment: Did you run the updated code? I get 6 as expected (you can try it right here in SO).

Comment: Oh I thought I did! At first it returned 4 even in the snippet! Thanks for your help and the quick reply!